# Why is this PHP if condition always true?

Tags: php, arrays, json, variables, if-statement

So right now I'm pulling data from a json API (battle.net) with this request

```
https://us.api.battle.net/wow/realm/status?locale=en_US&realms=runetotem&apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

API key hidden intentionally, this returns the following

```
{
  "realms": [{
    "type": "pve",
    "population": "medium",
    "queue": false,
    "wintergrasp": {
      "area": 1,
      "controlling-faction": 1,
      "status": 0,
      "next": 1433468324674
    },
    "tol-barad": {
      "area": 21,
      "controlling-faction": 1,
      "status": 2,
      "next": 1433465638814
    },
    "status": true,
    "name": "Runetotem",
    "slug": "runetotem",
    "battlegroup": "Vengeance",
    "locale": "en_US",
    "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "connected_realms": ["uther", "runetotem"]
  }]
}
```

Which I am putting into an array using php and then attempting to call upon values from said array in an if statement, however the if statement is always firing true for my check. I don't understand why at all, if someone could please help that'd be great. Code below.

```
<?php 
$json_url = "https://us.api.battle.net/wow/realm/status?locale=en_US&realms=runetotem&apikey=xxxxxxxxxxx";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
?>

<tr class="latestthreads_portal">

<td width="230px" class="trow3">
<strong>Realm Status</strong>
<span class="smalltext"><br />
<?php if ($data['realms'][0]['status'] == 2)
{
    echo "up";
    }
    else{
    echo "Down?";
    }
?>
    <br />

  <br /> <div class="border"></div>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Please excuse crappy formatting, in a rush.

Comment: debug it, echo | (`var_dump()`) the value you are checking

Comment: Try checking on type as well, so `if($data['realms'][0]['status'] === 2)`

Comment: `$data['realms'][0]['status']` is set to true.  Did you mean `$data['realms'][0]['wintergrasp']['status']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have comparison issues and data nesting issues, I think. It looks to me like you are comparing `if (2 == true)` which evaluates to `true` in php.
http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Also you are only checking the status of the "realms" array, not the status of "tol-barad" and "wintergrasp" objects, not sure what you wanted, exactly.

Comment: How did I not realise that 2 is true in php. rip.
And yes, I am intentionally only checking the status of the realms array. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: And that's why we use the `===` comparison operand.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the JSON you've provided, it looks like the value of `$data['realms'][0]['status']` is `true`.

So, your if statement will be doing type juggling to get both sides as booleans, `(bool)2` is true, so the condition will always match.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that you want:

```
$data['realms'][0]['status'] == 2
```

and not

```
$data['realms']['wintergrasp']['status'] == 2
```

edit based on comment:

```
if ($data['realms']['status'] == 2)
```

Comment: See above, I'm intentionally only checking the status of realms.

Answer (score 0):

When comaparing different types in PHP, use `===` instead of `==`. Always. Three equal signs means 'Is it IDENTICAL?' Two equal signs means 'Is this equivalent?'